# Use user inputted numbers(terminated by 0) and then calculate their squares and store it in a file-JAVA

Tags: java, file, for-loop, do-while

I tried to do it using arrays and loops but my first error is with the loop itself. The loop goes on even if the user inputs 0. I'm not being able to find out what's wrong. Help please.

Here's the codes:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Num2 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] num = new int[99];

    System.out.println("Enter a number or press 0 to stop: ");
    num[0] = input.nextInt();

    while(num[0] != 0)
    {
        for(int i=1; i < num.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Enter another number or press 0 to stop: ");
        num[i]= input.nextInt();

        do
        {
            System.out.println("Enter another number or press 0 to stop: ");
            num[i]= input.nextInt();
        }
        while(num[i] != 0);
    }

    }


    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Square.txt");
    PrintWriter square = null;

    try{
        square = new PrintWriter(fos);
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.print("Could not create/find file");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    int[] output = new int[num.length];

    for(int i=0; i <= num.length; i++)
    {
        output[i] = i*i;
    }

    for(int i=0; i <= num.length; i++)
    {
        square.print(num[i]+"\t\t"+output[i]+" ");

    }

    System.out.print("Done");
}

}
```

Comment: `<= num.length` change to `<`.

Answer (score 0):

You got infinite loop because of

```
while(num[0] != 0)//If first number enters is not 0 then infinite loop.
```

Also you should change `i <= num.length` to `i < num.length`

Sample Program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] num = new int[5];//Changed to 5 for testing

    for(int i=0; i < num.length; i++){//Getting 5 Numbers
            System.out.println("Enter another number or press 0 to stop: ");
            int n= input.nextInt();
            if(n%10 == 0)
            {
               num[i] = n/10;
               break;//Breaks on user gave input ends with 0
            }
            num[i] = n;
    }

    int[] output = new int[num.length];

    for(int i=0; i < num.length; i++)
    {
        output[i] = num[i]*num[i];//Calculating Square of entered numbers
    }

    for(int i=0; i < num.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(num[i]+"\t\t"+output[i]+" "); //printing instead of writing in file

    }

    System.out.print("Done");
}
```

Comment: But the loop needs to end when the user enters 0.

Comment: But if user enters 0 in between means then the while loop will broke right?

Comment: Yes it has to break. Then only the values entered before the 0 will be stored in the array. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: I edited the code like for loop to end if user enter 0 at end and hit enter.